# How to extend php class with additional fields cross-dependant with original fields?

Tags: php, calendar, php-carbon

I'm trying to extend [Carbon](https://packagist.org/packages/nesbot/carbon) to include the equivalent date on the [Hebrew calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar) (as opposed to the standard [Gregorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar)), as well as other related information.

That means a few extra fields...

```
protected $hYear    
protected $hMonth
protected $hDay
...
(and more)
```

In this scenario, Carbon's `$year`, `$month`, and `$day` are now dependent on `$hYear`, `$hMonth` and `$hDay`. - Any time any of those fields is modified, the other calendar date needs to be recalculated. It must remain impossible to have an instance with Gregorian and Hebrew dates which don't match up.

How can I accomplish this?

The first thing I tried was overriding Carbon's create method, adding a flag for if the date passed in the first three arguments was in Hebrew. Besides being pretty ugly (`create(5777, 5, 8, null, null, null, null, true`), I was having trouble with the static context thing, and I'll explain:

In that scenario, there are two paths when the create method is called. If the English date is passed in, you'll need to make an instance of carbon and then calculate the Hebrew date and set those fields in that instance. If you get the Hebrew date, you'll calculate the English date, then create the instance, and then set the extra fields. However, how do you set the fields without the issue of accessing dynamic stuff from static contexts? `$instance->hYear` and `self::$hYear` didn't work, and the setters I made complained about static stuff.

The second way I tried involved putting the conversion code in the constructor instead of the create method so it would be called on every creation, and outside of a static context. There are a few problems with this too. The smaller one is that the constructor is run once, so modification methods would also need to reference the conversion logic. I guess that's not the end of the world. The bigger problem is the redundancy: If you use `createFromDate()`, then the constructor will set the extra fields properly. But if you use `createFromHebrewDate()`, it will convert the date to english in order to initialize Carbon instance, and then the constructor will convert it back. That's redundant redundant.

For reference, here's [Carbon's code](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Carbon.php).

Here's the code I have so far:

```
<?php

namespace Nitrogen;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Nitrogen\Hebcal\HebcalDateConverterAPIRequest;

class Nitrogen extends Carbon
{
    /**
     * The month constants.
     */
    const NISAN = 0;
    const IYYAR = 1;
    const SIVAN = 2;
    const TAMUZ = 3;
    const AV = 4;
    const ELUL = 5;
    const TISHREI = 6;
    const CHESHVAN = 7;
    const KISLEV = 8;
    const TEVES = 9;
    const SHVAT = 10;
    const ADAR = 11;
    const ADAR_I = 12;
    const ADAR_II = 13;

    /**
     * Names of months of the year.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $hebrewMonths = array(
        self::NISAN => 'Nisan',
        self::IYYAR => 'Iyyar',
        self::SIVAN => 'Sivan',
        self::TAMUZ => 'Tamuz',
        self::AV => 'Av',
        self::ELUL => 'Elul',
        self::TISHREI => 'Tishrei',
        self::CHESHVAN => 'Cheshvan',
        self::KISLEV => 'Kislev',
        self::TEVES => 'Tevet',
        self::SHVAT => 'Shvat',
        self::ADAR_I => 'Adar1',
        self::ADAR_II => 'Adar2',
    );

    protected $hYear;
    protected $hMonth;
    protected $hDay;

    public function __construct($time = null, $tz = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($time, $tz);

        $request = new HebcalDateConverterAPIRequest();
        $request->setGregorianDate($this->year, self::$hebrewMonths[$this->month], $this->day);
        $response = $request->execute();
        $this->year = $response->hy;
        $this->month = $response->hm;
        $this->day = $response->hd; // todo deal with the redundancy of this way

    }

    public static function createFromHebrewDate($hYear, $hMonth, $hDay){
        $request = new HebcalDateConverterAPIRequest();
        $request->setHebrewDate($hYear, self::$hebrewMonths[$hMonth], $hDay);
        $response = $request->execute();
        $instance = parent::create($response->gy, $response->gm, $response->gd); // todo somewhere hebrew one needs isHebrew flag set properly
        return $instance;
    }

}
```

**TLDR;** When I extend a class and add a field to a method, how can I use a static create method which modifies the instance it creates after creation before returning it? And is there a better way to enforce the cross-dependency thing than copying over each of Carbon's date setters and changing the details?

Comment: I just had a quick look at the Github repository for Carbon, and it looks like hebrew translations are included by default. Using the Translator might be an easier way to acheive this than dealing with multiple calendar format in your application.

Comment: @WilliamPerron No, no, no!!! The [Hebrew calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar) is not just a translation of the English! It's based on lunar months, not solar like gregorian, and it shifts by a whole month 7 out of every 19 years! Translation is certainly not enough. I'll update the question to make that more clear.

Comment: check out PHP's native [calendar functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.calendar.php), it will still probably be easier than try to implement it yourself using inheritance.

Comment: @WilliamPerron Thanks, I hadn't known about those. However, that doesn't address the question at hand.

Comment: I don't think creating an object that inherits from `Carbon` would actually be a good idea as it is likely a case of the good ol' "[`Square` cannot inherit from `Rectangle`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238176/why-would-square-inheriting-from-rectangle-be-problematic-if-we-override-the-set)" case and a violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)